# Databricks pass Python parameters into a looped SQL script multiple times

Tags: python, sql, databricks

I am trying to create a python list with multiple variables that will then be used as values in a for loop that loops through a sql query that creates multiple tables but I can't seem to find an example that shows a parameter that is used multiple times.

```
list = ["a","b","c"]
for x in list:
sql = ''' 
create volatile table test_{} as (
select * from database.tablename_{}
) with data on commit preserve rows;

create volatile table test2_{} as (
select * from database.tablename2_{}
) with data on commit preserve rows;
'''
display(sql)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use so-called [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (Since Python 3.6), to interpolate the same variable into multiple places:

```py
list = ["a","b","c"]
for x in list:
    sql = f'''
create volatile table test_{x} as (
select * from database.tablename_{x}
) with data on commit preserve rows;

create volatile table test2_{x} as (
select * from database.tablename2_{x}
) with data on commit preserve rows;
'''
    print(sql)
```

or you can use `format` with numbered placeholders

```py
list = ["a","b","c"]
for x in list:
    sql = '''
create volatile table test_{0} as (
select * from database.tablename_{0}
) with data on commit preserve rows;

create volatile table test2_{0} as (
select * from database.tablename2_{0}
) with data on commit preserve rows;
'''.format(x)
    print(sql)
```